# How to interface with shell (BusyBox) in Android App

Tags: android, shell, busybox

I want to send commands to (and receive output from) the Android shell (BusyBox) from a standard Android App. How would I go about doing this? 1 hour of googling yielded no result.

Help very appreciated.

Regards,
Svante

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -la");
```

This will execute `ls -la` command and return you the process. If you want more complicated interaction you should use input and output stream: `proc.getInputStream()` and `proc.getOutputStream()`